# Python working after upgrade from windows 10 to windows 11

Tags: python, windows-11-upgrade

I would like to upgrade my windows 10 to windows 11 because I like the new look and features. I´m using python quite a lot recently which got me wondered: Does my Python installation still work after upgrading to windows 11?
Does anyone have experience with the upgrade?

Greetings and thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 11 is basically Windows 10 with a revamped user interface and
some added features.

There is no reason that Python will be affected by the upgrade.

However, you should not force this upgrade as long as Windows Update
is not listing it. You may check whether your computer fulfills the
requirements by using
[WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11),
but wait for Microsoft to authorize the upgrade for your computer model.

Comment: Sorry for the incredibly late answer... That´s exactly the info I was looking for. Thank you!